# Image at center of ImageView inside Nested LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to get the image at center of the imageviews named **divider1**,**divider2** and **divider3**. But all I am getting is this:-

[image: http://i.imgur.com/fiBglY5.jpg]

As you can see between the **score** and **comment** the image is little bit upwards shifted. The image is a 5x5 pixel 'dot'.

**My XML file:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#d3d3d3"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" 
            android:padding="2dp"/>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="2dp">
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_author"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:padding="2dp" />
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/divider1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/divider"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:padding="2dp"/>
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_domain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:padding="2dp" />
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/divider2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/divider"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:padding="2dp"/>
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" 
            android:padding="2dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/list_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/ll2"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="2dp" >
                <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:padding="2dp" />
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/divider3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/divider"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:padding="2dp"/>
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_comments"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:padding="2dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any Ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The image view is wrapping depend on it's content**

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Set the image view height to match the container. and then you centre the image inside:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/divider3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/divider"
    android:padding="2dp"/>
```

Set those in your imageView.